# Как правильно: автомобиля или автомобилем?

Tags: выбор-слов

*...овладеть навыками вождения автомобил**я**(**ем**).*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Вождение **чего?** Автомобил**я**.* Не ***чем.*** Поэтому правильно:

> *овладеть навыками вождения автомобил**я**.*

Цитирую [Грамоту](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C&all=x):

**ВОДИТЬ,** вожу, водишь; водящий
3. **(что).** Уметь управлять автомобилем; быть водителем, вагоновожатым. *В. машину. В. автобус, троллейбус. В. умеешь?*

Answer (score 3):

[вождение](https://all_words.academic.ru/10104/%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5), -я; ср. (1, 3 зн.). Вождение судов. Вождение поездов.
*Овладеть навыками вождения* (чего? Р. п.) *автомоби**ля.***

Путаница происходит из-за другого существительного — *управление* (после него требуется творительный падеж): *овладеть навыками управления* (чем? Т. п.) *автомобил**ем**.*